# I need to restrict age for below 18 years age from the current date in Php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to restrict age for below 18 years of age from the current date in Php using javascript or ajax. How can I do this?

Please check my code I want to calculate the age onblur or onSubmit Please go through the code.

```js
function getAge(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  var da = today.getDate() - birthDate.getDate();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  if (m < 0) {
    m += 12;
  }
  if (da < 0) {
    da += 30;
  }
  return age;
}
var age = getAge("1987/08/31");
alert(age);
if (age < 18) {
  alert("This age is restrict");

} else {

  alert("This age is allowed");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="dob" onBlur="function getAge(dateString)" />
</form>
```

Comment: There are a million threads regarding that topic, google or use the search function.

Comment: You need to restrict what? Below 18 years old based on what?

Comment: Below 18 years old based on the given Date of birth by the user

Comment: Any code to show? Did you try anything?

Comment: Actually i am confused can you please give me script for doing the same

Comment: @Sam this site is not a Freelancer site. People are here to help you with what you ALREADY HAVE, not give everything to you. Use google do some research then come back if you get stuck supplying code.

Comment: I think stackoverflow should restrict this 18 years below to ask questoins. heh

Comment: I have post my answer check it and let me know

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 <script>
function getAge() {
var dateString = document.getElementById("date").value;
if(dateString !="")
{
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    var da = today.getDate() - birthDate.getDate();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    if(m<0){
        m +=12;
    }
    if(da<0){
        da +=30;
    }

  if(age < 18 || age > 100)
{
alert("Age "+age+" is restrict");

} else {

alert("Age "+age+" is allowed");
}
} else {
alert("please provide your date of birth");
}
}


</script>
<input type="text" id="date" value="1987/08/31" onblur="getAge()">
```

http://js.do/code/65643

Comment: Please check my code i want to calculate the age onblur or onSubmit Please go through the code

Comment: Please check my answer which i have posted right now

Comment: yes but not working onSubmit or onBlur while i'm refreshing the page a popup comes and shows in popup '27' that's it

Comment: tell me one more thing that in else part we can display the accurate age in years according to the given date of birth?

Comment: Deena how we can restrict that age limit should be maximum 100 year not more than that please make this changes in the script

Comment: you want minimum 18 or maximum 100 or both?

Comment: i want both and moreover that if user does not give the input than alert should be like "please provide your date of birth"

Comment: 2nd else condition is not working can we use else if instead of else?

Answer (score 0):

Here Another Example Of Age Validation 
Please Try It

```js
 function getAge() 
 {
  var dateString = document.getElementById("date").value;
  alert(dateString);
  
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear()-18; 
  alert(year);
  var month=0;
   if(today.getMonth() < 10)
   {
    month="0"+(today.getMonth()+1);
   }
   else
   {
    month=(today.getMonth()+1);
   }
   alert(month);
   var day=0;
   if(today.getDate() < 10)
   {
    day="0"+today.getDate();
   }
   else
   {
    day=today.getDate();
   }
   alert(day);
  
  var str = year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day;
  var date1 = new Date();
   date1 = str;
   
   alert(str);
  
  if (dateString>str)
     {
     alert("You Are NOt Able To Join Us!");
     }
   else
     {
     alert("You Are Able To Join Us!");
     }
     
 }
</script>
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" />

<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn" name="B4" onclick="return getAge();">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->input->post('age'));
            $dob = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
            $today = new DateTime('today');
            $age = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
            if ($age >= 18) { true } else { false }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another example of how you could get this to work which might be cleaner!

```js
function getAge() 
{
    var dateString = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    if(dateString !="")
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(dateString); //format is mm.dd.yyyy
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

        if(age < 18 || age > 100)
        {
            alert("Age "+age+" is restrict");
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("Age "+age+" is allowed");
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("please provide your date of birth");
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="date" id="dob">
<br>

<input type="button" value="Get Age" onclick="return getAge()">

</body>
```